# Write text behind image keeping everything responsive

Tags: html, css, layout

This is what I'm trying to achieve through HTML/CSS on my website:

[image]

I want to add a **div** of text behind an image which I have been able to achieve on a laptop screen but I am struggling to keep it from overlapping with the text to the image's right when I resize the screen. How can I keep this structure responsive?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot with absolute positions and z-index.

In the following example I've used absolute positions and percentages to keep the responsiveness intact, and i've used z-index to overlap the bottom div.

Click *Full Page* to test it out. Hope this helps.

```css
.background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 350px;
  width: 30%;
  background: blue;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.imagetext {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="imagetext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Why not break the text into a new row on mobile and have it below the image?

Comment: Why is your answer a question?